# Javafx multiples pantallas fullScreen

Tags: javafx, screen

He realizado una aplicacion que al presionar en un boton, crea en caso de que la pc tenga otro monitor conectado, una stage fullscreen en dicho monitor, Ahora la pregunta es, sera posible que cuando el stage que esta fullscreen pierde el focus, la barra de tarea del sistema operativo no se vaya por delante de dicha app?...

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Lo mejor será que añadas el código con lo que has intentado y qué resultados has obtenido. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución sería:

Primero necesitamos la identificación del monitor primario:

```
int primaryMon;
Screen primary = Screen.getPrimary();
for(int i = 0; i < Screen.getScreens().size(); i++){
    if(Screen.getScreens().get(i).equals(primary)){
        primaryMon = i;
        System.out.println("primary: " + i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Después de esto iniciamos y mostramos la etapa primaria. Es importante hacer esto en el monitor principal (para ocultar barras de tareas y cosas por el estilo).

```
Screen screen2 = Screen.getScreens().get(primaryMon);
Stage stage2 = new Stage();
stage2.setScene(new Scene(new Label("primary")));
//tenemos que establecer la posición de la ventana en el monitor principal:
stage2.setX(screen2.getVisualBounds().getMinX());
stage2.setY(screen2.getVisualBounds().getMinY());
stage2.setFullScreen(true);
stage2.show();
```

Ahora la parte de la solución. Creamos las etapas para los otros monitores:

```
Label label = new Label("monitor " + i);
stage.setScene(new Scene(label));
System.out.println(Screen.getScreens().size());
Screen screen = Screen.getScreens().get(i); //i es el id del monitor

//establecer la posición a uno de los "slave" -monitores:
stage.setX(screen.getVisualBounds().getMinX());
stage.setY(screen.getVisualBounds().getMinY());

//establecer las dimensiones para el tamaño de la pantalla:
stage.setWidth(screen.getVisualBounds().getWidth());
stage.setHeight(screen.getVisualBounds().getHeight());

//muestra el escenario sin decoraciones (barra de título y bordes de ventana):
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
stage.show();
```

Comment: J. Rodriguez gracias por su respuesta pero eso ya lo tenía conseguido, solo me faltaba poner al segundo stage stageFullScreen.initOwner(stagePrincipal); y así la segunda pantalla no pierde el focus cuando pasamos el raton a la primera, sino pudiera darse el caso que la barra de tarea de windows se vaya por encima de la aplicación y aunque esta este fullscreen no se mostraría completa sino que tendría la barra de tarea delante!!!

Comment: @RafaelMayor ok, excelente